# How do I insert data from one table to another when there is unequal number of rows in one another?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table named `People` that has 19370 rows with `playerID` being the primary column. There is another table named `Batting`, which has `playerID` as a foreign key and has 104324 rows.

I was told to add a new column in the `People` table called `Total_HR`, which is included in the `Batting` table. So, I have to insert that column data from the `Batting` table into the `People` table.

However, I get the error:

> Msg 515, Level 16, State 2, Line 183 Cannot insert the value NULL into
>   column 'playerID', table 'Spring_2019_BaseBall.dbo.People'; column
>   does not allow nulls. INSERT fails. The statement has been terminated.

I have tried `UPDATE` and `INSERT INTO SELECT`, however got the same error

```
insert into People (Total_HR)
select sum(HR) from Batting group by playerID
```

I expect the output to populate the column `Total_HR` in the `People` table using the `HR` column from the `Batting` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a join

```
BEGIN TRAN

Update  People
Set     Total_HR = B.HR_SUM
from    PEOPLE              A   
    left outer join
        (Select playerID, sum(HR) HR_SUM 
        from Batting 
        group by playerID)  B   on A.playerID = B.playerID

Select * from People

ROLLBACK
```

Notice that I've put this code in a transaction block so you can test the changes before you commit

Comment: do i add the keyword "commit" in place of "rollback" because this one actually worked

Answer (score 1):

From the error message, it seems that playerID is a required field in table People.
You need to specify all required fields of table People in the INSERT INTO clause and provide corresponding values in the SELECT clause.

I added field playerID below, but you might need to add additional required fields as well.

```
insert into People (playerID, Total_HR)
select playerID, sum(HR) from Batting group by playerID
```

It is strange, however, that you want to insert rows in a table that should already be there. Otherwise, you could not have a valid foreign key on field playerID in table Batting... If you try to insert such rows from table Batting into table People, you might get another error (violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint)... Unless... you are creating the database just now and you want to populate empty table People from filled/imported table Batting before adding the actual foreign key constraint to table People. Sorry, I will not question your intentions. I personally would consider to update the query somewhat so that it will not attempt to insert any rows that already exist in table People:

```
insert into People (playerID, Total_HR)
select Batting.playerID, sum(Batting.HR)
from Batting
left join People on People.playerID = Batting.playerID
where People.playerID is null and Batting.playerID is not null
group by playerID
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate the `SUM` and then join this result to the `People` table to bring into the same rows both `Total_HR` column from `People` and the corresponding SUM calculated from `Batting`.

Here is one way to write it. I used CTE to make is more readable.

```
WITH
CTE_Sum
AS
(
    SELECT
        Batting.playerID
        ,SUM(Batting.HR) AS TotalHR_Src
    FROM
        Batting
    GROUP BY
        Batting.playerID
)
,CTE_Update
AS
(
    SELECT
        People.playerID
        ,People.Total_HR
        ,CTE_Sum.TotalHR_Src
    FROM
        CTE_Sum
        INNER JOIN People ON People.playerID = CTE_Sum.playerID
)
UPDATE CTE_Update
SET 
    Total_HR = TotalHR_Src
;
```